# Get next row if coloumn has same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day, I'm trying to select a data. Please check my query and table first.

I have this query

```
select * from 
    ( 
SELECT *    from 
(
 select distinct TOP 201233 row, b.OutletCode as 'Kode Otlet', 
 i.Description as 'Area', 
 c.Nilai,a.Nip, b.Fullname 'Nama Lengkap', f.positioncode as 'Posisi Sebelumnya', 
 case when a.[status]=0 
    then j.ApprovedDate else p.ApprovedDate 
    end as 'Tanggal Upgrade/Demosi Sebelumnya', 
d.positioncode as 'Posisi Baru', a.tanggal as 'Tanggal Upgrade/Demosi' 
from penilaian_header a 
left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip 
left join Position f on b.PositionCode = f.PositionCode 
left join Position d on a.PositionCode = d.PositionCode 
left join arealeader g on g.OutletCode = b.OutletCode 
left join outlet h on g.OutletCode = h.OutletCode 
left join area i on i.areacode = h.areacode 
left join cutoff k on a.periode = k.cutoffcode 
left join 
    (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KodePenilaianH ORDER BY idPenilaiand ASC) AS Row, 
    Nilai,KodePenilaianH from penilaian_Detail ) c on a.KodePenilaian = c.KodePenilaianH 
left join 
    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nip ORDER BY ApprovedDate desc) AS rownumber, 
    ApprovedDate, Nip FROM historyposition ) AS p on a.nip=p.nip and p.rownumber = 2 
    left join ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nip ORDER BY ApprovedDate desc) AS rownumber, ApprovedDate, Nip 
    FROM historyposition ) AS j on a.nip=j.nip and j.rownumber = 1 
    where a.flag = 1 and h.AreaCode like '%%'
     and Periode like '%CO-2016-9-16-15%' and a.nip = '1004863'
     --and tanggal <= k.[to] and tanggal >= k.[from] 
     order by i.Description asc) nilai pivot ( sum(nilai) for row in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) ) piv)A order by Area;
```

with above query i get this result

[image]

and i have this table `HistoryPosition`
[image]

```
KodeMutasiP OldPosition NewPosition ApprovedBy  ApprovedDate    Nip KodePenilaian
HP0000514       P007    P007         0802678    2016-09-15     1004863  PE0000787
HP0000513       P007    P007         0802678    2016-04-04      1004863 PE0000130
NULL            NULL    P007         NULL       2016-04-04      1004863 NULL
NULL            NULL    P041         NULL       2016-01-20      1004863 NULL
NULL            NULL    P007         NULL       2015-02-12      1004863 NULL
```

ok. So what i want to do is set `Posisi Sebelumnya` and `Tanggal Upgrade/Demosi Sebelumnya` in the first picture with `newposition` and `Approveddate` from the second picture.

But with this condition 
if `newposition` and `nip` col in the second picture same with the second row then jump to the second, if the second same with the third then jump to the fourth, if the fourth different with the third then choose the third.

I have write the query to choose it here is my query

```
select * INTO #tMP from historyposition where nip = '1004863' order by approveddate desc

declare @NewPosition varchar(50), @NewPositionLast varchar(50), @ApproveDate datetime, @ApproveDateLast datetime
select top 1 @NewPositionLast = NewPosition, @ApproveDateLast=ApprovedDate from #tmp
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tMP)
BEGIN
    select top 1 @NewPosition = NewPosition, @ApproveDate=ApprovedDate from #tmp
    if (@NewPosition = @NewPositionLast)
    begin 
        set @NewPositionLast = @NewPosition 
        set @ApproveDateLast = @ApproveDate
    end 
    else
    begin
        break
    end
    delete top(1) #tMP
END
select  @NewPositionLast , @ApproveDateLast
drop table #tMP
```

and i get this result

```
|  P007 |  2016-04-04 00:00:00.000 |
```

the result is like what i expected.

so my question how to set the `Posisi Sebelumnya` and `Tanggal Upgrade/Demosi Sebelumnya` with the result of my last query.

Sorry for my bad english.

here it's my expected result .

[image]

I know it's same with the the first picture. But its not right. that because in my first query i choose the second row.

---

```
select * from 
( 
SELECT * from 
    ( 
select distinct TOP 201233 row, b.OutletCode as 'Kode Otlet', i.Description as 'Area', 
c.Nilai,a.Nip, b.Fullname 'Nama Lengkap', 
case when 
    l.ShortDesc  IS NULL then f.ShortDesc else  l.ShortDesc 
end
    as 'PosisiSebelumnya',
-----
z.approveddate,
------
d.ShortDesc as 'Posisi Baru', a.tanggal as 'Tanggal Upgrade/Demosi' 
from penilaian_header a 
    left join Employee b on a.Nip = b.Nip 
    left join Position f on b.PositionCode = f.PositionCode 
    left join Position d on a.PositionCode = d.PositionCode 
    left join position l on a.posisisaatini = l.positioncode
    left join arealeader g on g.OutletCode = b.OutletCode 
    left join outlet h on g.OutletCode = h.OutletCode 
    left join area i on i.areacode = h.areacode 
    left join cutoff k on a.periode = k.cutoffcode 
    left join 
    (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY KodePenilaianH ORDER BY idPenilaiand ASC) AS Row, 
    Nilai,KodePenilaianH from penilaian_Detail ) c on a.KodePenilaian = c.KodePenilaianH 
    left join (
    select top(1) Nip,NewPosition, ApprovedDate
        from (
            select Nip,NewPosition,ApprovedDate
            , grp = row_number() over(order by ApprovedDate desc) - row_number() over(partition by NewPosition order by ApprovedDate desc)
            from HistoryPosition
        ) t
        where grp = 0
        order by ApprovedDate
    )z on z.Nip = a.Nip
    where a.flag = 1 
    and h.AreaCode like '%%' 
    and Periode like '%CO-2016-9-16-15%' 
    and tanggal <= k.[to] and tanggal >= k.[from] order by i.Description asc) nilai 
    pivot ( sum(nilai) for row in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) ) piv)A order by Area;
```

i get this.

[image]

Comment: Show sample data and expected output please.

Comment: @NEER i've update my question. It's same with the first picture but the first result i use the second row not the third row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last script retrievs the row with the minimum ApprovedDate. It should be effectively the same as

```
SELECT ApprovedDate, NewPosition
FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NewPosition ORDER BY ApprovedDate asc) AS rownumber, ApprovedDate, NewPosition
   FROM historyposition 
   WHERE nip = '1004863') t
WHERE rownumber = 1
```

Try to use this snippet in your bigger query.

**EDIT**
Detect first group of `NewPosition` when `historyposition` is odered by `ApprovedDate desc` and take first row witn `min  ApprovedDate` in group.

```
with HistoryPosition as(
    -- sample data
    select sKodeMutasiP,OldPosition,NewPosition,ApprovedBy
       ,cast(ApprovedDate as DATE) ApprovedDate, Nip,KodePenilaian
    from (
        values
         ('HP0000514','P007','P007',0802678,'2016-09-15',1004863,'PE0000787')
        ,('HP0000513','P007','P007',0802678,'2016-04-04',1004863,'PE0000130')
        ,(NULL,NULL,'P007',NULL,'2016-04-04',1004863,NULL)
        ,(NULL,NULL,'P041',NULL,'2016-01-20',1004863,NULL)
        ,(NULL,NULL,'P007',NULL,'2015-02-12',1004863,NULL)
    ) t (sKodeMutasiP,OldPosition,NewPosition,ApprovedBy,ApprovedDate,Nip,KodePenilaian)
)
select top(1) NewPosition, ApprovedDate
from (
    select NewPosition,ApprovedDate
    , grp = row_number() over(order by ApprovedDate desc) - row_number() over(partition by NewPosition order by ApprovedDate desc)
    from HistoryPosition
    where nip = 1004863
) t
where grp = 0
order by ApprovedDate;
```

**EDIT2**
Use this snippet in OUTER APPLY instead of LEFT JOIN as it depends on other table data:

```
...
outer apply(
    select top(1) NewPosition, ApprovedDate
    from (
        select NewPosition,ApprovedDate
        , grp = row_number() over(order by ApprovedDate desc) - row_number() over(partition by NewPosition order by ApprovedDate desc)
        from HistoryPosition hp
        where hp.nip = a.nip -- other table 
    ) t
    where grp = 0
    order by ApprovedDate
    ) npa
```

...

Comment: well. I think it's not the `minimum` because i still have the same value check row number 5.

Comment: and with your query i get this  `2013-11-05 | P007` because in earlier date he has different `newposition`. that is P041.

Comment: I see.  You need min date from first group of  `NewPosition` when  source table is ordered by `ApprovedDate desc`. It can be done by extra row_numbering. Please provide  `HistoryPosition`  data in text format instead of pictire so someone can help you.

Comment: i have a problem when i'm trying to join it with my first query. I get null.

Comment: Use outer apply instead of left join. This way you can use other table column in where.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is, how can I combine two result sets so that they appear in a single row, the following select can be used:

```
-- first select
select 1 one, 2 two, 3 three, 0 joinCondition

-- second select
select 'a' a, 'b' b, 'c' c, 0 joinCondition

-- combined
select one, two, three, a, b, c
from (select 1 one, 2 two, 3 three, 0 joinCondition) first
   inner join (select 'a' a, 'b' b, 'c' c, 0 joinCondition) second
      on first.joinCondition = second.joinCondition
```

The idea is, we add  a dummy column to both selects with equal value so that it can be used to join them